# Items in Action Bar won't show in App

Tags: android, xml, icons, android-actionbar

I have a problem: I want to put a search Icon on the Action Bar. In Android Studio it shows it on the Action Bar, but when I open the App it only shows it in the menu..

Here is my xml code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
```

I tried many things but it wont work. I hope you can help me.
It still doesn't work I really don't have a clue why.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying your ActionView class, which is probably part of the problem.  Here is the xml for a search action view that I use in one of my applications that works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_user"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/magnifing_glass"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>

</menu>
```

EDIT:

If you're not trying to use it as an ActionView, disregard the above and use `showAsAction="always"`.

Comment: actionViewClass is only necessary for ActionProviders, see docs:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: You're right, I guess that was a bit of an assumption as the OP didn't explicitly state how they were using the search icon.  Still, showAsAction="always" will likely fix the issue, as reflected in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either that there is not enough space on the action bar to display the icon, or your device has a dedicated menu button.